# How to find the extents in an array of nested objects?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of nested objects containing values like GDP, income, population etc. per year per state:

```
// The "records" array looks like this:
[
    {
        name : "...",
        income : [
            [1995, 1234], // [year, value]
            [1996. 1235],
            [...]
        ],
        GDP : [
            [1995, 1234],
            [1996. 1235],
            [...]
        ],
        population : [
            [1995, 1234],
            [1996. 1235],
            [...]
        ]
    }, {
        name : "...",
        income : [
            [...]
        ],
        GDP : [
            [...]
        ],
        population : [
            [...]
        ]
    }, {
        ...
    }
]
```

Now, I want to find the minimum and maximum (extent) for each dimension over all states and years.

```
populationExtents = [659651, 82536680];
gdpExtents        = [14250, 2498800];
incomeExtents     = [..., ...];
```

How can I do this without having to traverse the whole array multiple times? Currently, I'm doing this for each dimension:

```
var income = records.map(function(d, i) {
    return d.income;
});

var min = d3.min(income, function(d, i) {
    return d3.min(d, function(e) {
            return e[1]; // returns values of each year
        });
});

var max = d3.max(income, function(d, i) {
    return d3.max(d, function(e) {
            return e[1];
        });
});
```

But I think this is way too complex, since I should be able to calculate all "local" minimums per dimension and state, and then calculate the global minimum over all states in just on pass (instead of one pass per each dimension).

I tried several levels of d3.map and nested d3.min, but am not able to wrap my head around this structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getMaxMin( prop ) {
    var concat = [].concat,
        arr = concat.apply([], records.map(function(value) {
            return concat.apply([], value[prop]);
        }));

    return [ Math.min.apply(Math.min, arr), Math.max.apply(Math.max, arr) ];
}
```

Or a little prettier:

```
function getMaxMin( prop ) {
    var arr = [];

    records.map(function(value) {
        arr = arr.concat.apply(arr, value[prop][1]);
    });

    return [ Math.min.apply(Math.min, arr), Math.max.apply(Math.max, arr) ];
}
```

---

**EDIT:** To exclude year `[year, value]` and putting almost everything under the same loop:

```
function getMaxMin() {
    var arrs = [];

    records.map(function(value) {
        arrs[0] = arrs[0].concat(value.income);
        arrs[1] = arrs[1].concat(value.GDP);
        arrs[2] = arrs[2].concat(value.population);
    });

    arrs[0] = arrs[0].filter(c);
    arrs[1] = arrs[1].filter(c);
    arrs[2] = arrs[2].filter(c);

    function c(value, key) {
        return key % 2;
    }

    return [
        [ Math.min.apply(Math.min, arrs[0]), Math.max.apply(Math.max, arrs[0]) ],
        [ Math.min.apply(Math.min, arrs[1]), Math.max.apply(Math.max, arrs[1]) ],
        [ Math.min.apply(Math.min, arrs[2]), Math.max.apply(Math.max, arrs[2]) ]
    ];
}

var maxMin = getMaxMin();

maxMin === [
    [income-min, income-max],
    [GDP-min, GDP-max],
    [population-min, population-max]
]
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ecineg/1/embed?javascript,console

Comment: I'm sorry If this was a bit unclear: `[199x, 1234]` was meant as `[year, value]`. Your code includes the year in the calculated min/max values. I edited to post to clarify this.

Comment: Great, this works. Thank you! However, IIUC it needs on call per prop (and thus one map and on filter each). I suppose there is no (reasonable) way to do it with just a single map/filter?

Comment: Hey dev-null... in the prettier version. instead of `arr = arr.concat.apply(arr, value[prop][1]);`, why not just do `arr = arr.concat(value[prop][1]);`?

Comment: @AndyPerlitch The difference is that `arr.concat.apply([1,[2,3,4],5])`will be flattened to `[1,2,3,4,5]` while `arr.concat([1,[2,3,4],5])` will give `[1,[2,3,4],5]`. But I dont know is this have anything to do in this context. It is an old answer after all :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `Math.max` and `Math.min` functions with `apply` to get the max and min of an array. To get the arrays I am using `reduce` and concating the property of each record

```
var allValues = function (property) {
  return records.reduce(function (memo, record) {
    return memo.concat(record[property])
  }, [])
}

var allIncome = allValues('income')

Math.max.apply(null, allIncome)
Math.min.apply(null, allIncome)
```

Comment: `allValues('income')` returns: `[ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8] ]` not `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`